# PHP_SELF redirecting to id

Tags: php

I have a page and I put a form but it refresh to the top instead than to the form, meaning that you have to scroll down to see the result of the form.

```
action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>"
```

Is there anyway to redirect it to the form? I put an id to the form but I have no knowledge of php.

The page is a CMS Wordpress and the form is in php (copy and paste)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>#id_of_your_form"` should do the trick. You need to make sure your form has an ID attribute as well.

Note your user may miss any messages generated by PHP if they are displayed at the top of the page. Hard to give a better answer without more details.